# Does an API standard for price feeds exist?

Tags: erc-20, data-feeds, interfaces

The [ERC 20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20) defines a standard interface for designing a token contract. Does a similar standard exist for defining feeds that can be called by other contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Ethereum Project under ["Standardized Contract APIs"](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Standardized_Contract_APIs#data-feeds), a small standard for feeds is defined. I do not know if it is the most widely used standard, though.

This standard defines two required methods:
`set(bytes32 _key, <t> _value)` and `get(bytes32 _key) returns (<t> _r)` where `<t>` should be replaced the data type in question (e.g. uint256, address etc.) The `key` argument comes together with a `value` and the key/value pair will usually be store in a mapping which is a key/value datastructure similar to a dict in Python or a hash in Perl.

There are also two optional methods: setFee(uint256 _fee) and setFeeCurrency(address _feeCurrency) which, I think, denotes how you pay for getting the information in question.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.